# Using Github pages with Jekyll in a subdirectory

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I recently wanted to publish my Jekyll site on Github pages, but it seems that putting everything in a subdirectory is giving some issues, even after I change the `source` to the correct directory.

My structure looks like this:

```
- site
   - src (contains all Jekyll stuff)
   - README.md
   - GruntFile.js
   - ...
```

Locally my site builds perfectly and when I go to `http://localhost:4040` I can see it just nicely, but when I commit this to my Github and visit `username.github.io` I get a 404, if I go to `username.github.io/src` I can see part of my site, however all `{% include %}` are ignored.

In my `_config.yml` I updated the source: `source: ./src`, but that doesn't seem to help.

Is there a way to make Github Pages handle subdirectories properly? Basically I want to tell it that my Jekyll site is inside `/src`, and I want the url to just be `username.github.io` instead of `username.github.io/src`

I know i can use the pages branch and commit to there, but I would prefer if it could happen automaticly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contact Github support and they gave me 2 solutions.

1. Move all my Jekyll source files to my top-lever directory.
2. Use a different branch and update it manually each time.

Comment: mgp asks: Woutr_be, thanks for your answer. I have the same problem.

I understand point 1, but could you elaborate on point 2? Or point me to more info?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Alice, basically Github allows you to create a branch called `gh-pages`, which, if it exists will use those files as your Github page. So when working with a different structure, you can manually push your compiled Jekyll site to that branch. Of course this is a bit of a hassle.

Answer (score 4):

If it helps anyone, I attempted to run Jekyll on GH Pages from a subdir (and modified `source`) and was banging my head against the wall over these errors:

> A file was included in `subdir/index.html` that is a symlink or does not exist in your `_includes` directory. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-file-is-a-symlink.

After much searching on this, the definitive answer was right there in the [docs](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/):

> ### Configuration Overrides
>
> We override the following `_config.yml` values, which you are unable to
>   configure:
>
> ```
> safe: true
> lsi: false
> source: your top-level directory
> ```
>
> Keep in mind that if you change the `source` setting, your pages may not
>   build correctly. GitHub Pages only considers source files in the
>   top-level directory of a repository.